# SQL server deadlock graph explained

Tags: sql-server, database-deadlocks

I am testing a scenario or recurrent request that ends up in executing the following store procedure simultaneously

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[clear_class]( @classID [int])
AS
BEGIN 

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[class_action]
  WHERE class_id=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[page_item_image] 
  WHERE class_id=@classID;

  DELETE pis
  FROM [dbo].[page_item_spec] as pis 
  JOIN page_item AS pit ON (pis.pi_id=pit.pi_id AND pit.pi_owner=@classID) 

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[page_item] 
  WHERE pi_owner=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[page] 
  WHERE page_owner=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[image] 
  WHERE img_owner=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[class_style] 
  WHERE class_id=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[style] 
  WHERE sty_owner=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[class_text] 
  WHERE class_id=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[text] 
  WHERE text_owner=@classID;

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[action] 
  WHERE act_owner=@classID;
END
```

and I get deadlock exceptions.
The deadlock graph is the following:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process2f7f61848">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process2f7f61848" taskpriority="0" logused="55572" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594104315904 (81110f5858a7)" waittime="2947" ownerId="161655" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.427" XDES="0x2effb83b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="9908" status="suspended" spid="59" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.427" lastbatchcompleted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.417" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.417" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="MVERG" hostpid="8084" loginname="menelaos" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="161655" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="db.dbo.p_clear_class" line="15" stmtstart="722" stmtend="874" sqlhandle="0x03000500dfae3842b1f7fa006ea4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[page_item_image] with(rowlock)
    WHERE class_id=@classI     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1111011039]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process2f53ff468" taskpriority="0" logused="425956" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057594104119296 (cc50c8bdfc5d)" waittime="2921" ownerId="161454" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.303" XDES="0x2eed31000" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="8516" status="suspended" spid="61" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.303" lastbatchcompleted="2015-04-02T15:36:12.303" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.303" clientapp="EntityFramework" hostname="MVERG" hostpid="8084" loginname="menelaos" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="161454" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="db.dbo.p_clear_class" line="40" stmtstart="2108" stmtend="2244" sqlhandle="0x03000500dfae3842b1f7fa006ea4000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
DELETE FROM [dbo].[text] with(rowlock)
    WHERE text_owner=@classI     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 5 Object Id = 1111011039]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594104315904" dbid="5" objectname="db.dbo.page_item_image" indexname="PK_page_item_image" id="lock2ef2e4900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594104315904">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process2f53ff468" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process2f7f61848" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594104119296" dbid="5" objectname="db.dbo.page_item" indexname="PK_page_item" id="lock2f02ee900" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594104119296">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process2f7f61848" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process2f53ff468" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

I see that the problem has something to do with the lock mode, the table is lock mode 's' and need lock mode 'x' but the other process has already lock the table with 'u'...

What do I have to do the solve this deadlock? Is it because of execution order? Does IX lock solves anything and if so how I can set that?

Comment: Are there any foreign keys between any of the tables, such as between the text table and the page_item_image table?

Comment: There is no direct constrain between them. The 'Text' table is quite popular since it's used from several tables but not from page_item_image.

Comment: Are there any foreign keys between page_item and page_item_image?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but you can try this and see if it helps.

At the moment all the delete statements are being executed in ONE batch. So if a delete statement obtains an `Exclusive` or `Update` lock the following statement is getting blocked if it needs to access the same resources.

Create Two new procedures to execute the delete statements, separately in their own batches. One for the standard single table delete statement and One for the delete you are doing by joining two tables (otherwise One proc should have been enough)

### Delete data Procedures

**Procedure One**

this procedure to delete data from single table at a time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Delete_Class 
 @TableName SYSNAME
,@classID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SET @Sql = N'DELETE FROM [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
         + N' WHERE class_id = @classID; '   

Exec sp_executesql @Sql  
                  ,N'@classID INT'
                  ,@classID

 IF @@ERROR = 0 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 ELSE 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

**Procedure 2**

for deleting data by joining two tables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Delete_Class_page_item_spec
 @classID INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DELETE pis
  FROM [dbo].[page_item_spec] as pis 
  JOIN page_item AS pit ON (pis.pi_id=pit.pi_id AND pit.pi_owner=@classID) 

 IF @@ERROR = 0 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION;
 ELSE 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```

### Main Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[clear_class]
  @classID INT
AS
BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'class_action' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'page_item_image' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class_page_item_spec  @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'page_item' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'page' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'image' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'Class_Style' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'Style' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'Class_Text' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'Text' , @classID

  Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class 'Action' , @classID

END
```

Comment: Unfortunately now it deadlocks at the `Exec dbo.usp_Delete_Class` :-(